# Convert and compare NSString and NSDate

Tags: swift, nsstring, nsdate, converters

I've some problem with a function that convert and compare a NSString with NSDate in swift.

```
func Parse(pouet : NSString, Limite : NSDate) {
        let word = pouet.componentsSeparatedByString("\"")

        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"

        for var index = 11; (index < word.count-6); index+=6 {
            var datefromstring = dateFormatter.dateFromString(word[index] as String)

            if (((datefromstring?.isEqualToDate(Limite))) != nil) {
                println("<<<")
                println(datefromstring)
                println(Limite)
                println(">>>")
            }
        }
    }
```

Output :

```
<<<
Optional(2014-12-02 10:30:00 +0000)
2014-12-04 18:36:32 +0000
>>>
```

What's wrong ? I juste want print only when DateFromString and Limite are the same (OR ideally when Limite is upper that datefromstring).

Thanks by advance.

Comment: function and variable names should begin with a small letter, not a capital letter

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> if (((datefromstring?.isEqualToDate(Limite))) != nil) {
> ```

Well, think about it: `datefromstring?.isEqualToDate(Limite)` is either YES or NO (Swift `true` or `false`). Neither of those is `nil`. So this condition always succeeds.

It is true that this `true` or `false` is wrapped up in an Optional. That's because you're calling `isEqualToDate` on an Optional. But then what you're testing here is whether the Optional `datefromstring` was nil - you are not testing for whether what it wraps is `true` vs. `false`, since they *both* are non-nil.

Thus you are not expressing the distinction you're wishing to express.

Comment: Yes, I'm still writing, Nate. Cool your jets.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to use optional binding for the `dateFromString` result, then use the date's `compare` method in a switch statement:

```
if let datefromstring = dateFormatter.dateFromString(word[index] as String) {
    switch datefromstring.compare(Limite) {
    case .OrderedAscending:
        println("datefromstring before Limite")
    case .OrderedDescending:
        println("datefromstring after Limite")
    case .OrderedSame:
        println("exact match!")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank's for this, but not working : datefromstring before Limite
2014-12-03 11:30:00
2014-12-03 13:30:00
2014-12-04 14:00:00
2014-12-04 14:30:00
2014-12-04 15:00:00
2014-12-04 15:30:00
datefromstring after Limite

Comment: What's not working? I don't know what all that means.

Comment: Well, some date don't match, limite is 2014-12-04 19:38:03 then, this 3 date 2014-12-02 11:30:00, 2014-12-02 13:30:00 and 2014-12-02 15:00:00 match no case...

Comment: Did you delete one of the cases? If you get through to the switch it *has* to match one of them. You might want to add an else to the `if let...` to see if there are dates that aren't parsing (although those look fine).

Comment: No cases delete. I try your "else" tips, and effectively, sometime dateFormatter.dateFromString(word[index] return nil (but word[index] is not nil), and in this case, no match with switch case.

Comment: Thx for your help, I find error with switch case and else type. I change this dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss " add space after ss after analysing string.